# HIve query combined table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata

could you please help with below query.

I have three input table (Table1 , table 2 , table 3)

[image]

The output table should have below columns

**Date :** (combine all the payment_date, receive_date, maturity_date),
**payment_amount** (populate the correct amount for a given payment_date),
**receive_amount** (populate the correct amount for a given receive_date),
**maturity_amount** (populate the correct amount for a given maturity_date),
**total** (payment_amount + receive_amount+ maturity_amount) for a given date column

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive supports `FULL JOIN`, so you can use:

```
select coalesce(t1.payment_date, t2.receiver_date, t3.maturity_date) as date,
       t1.payment_amount,
       t2.receive_amount,
       t3.maturity_amount
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on t2.receive_date = t1.payment_date full join
     table3 t3
     on t3.maturity_date in (t2.receive_date, t1.payment_date)
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff for the response.  there are values in maturity_date, payment_date and recieve_date which are not  having the same date. how to combine those values in the same table.

Comment: @smp97 . . . I don't understand your question.  That is what this answer does.